# Can Git be made to deal with logical rather than physical changes?

Tags: git, workflow

Are there workflows that allow using Git to record the *logic* of how changes are made when the physical mechanics of the change diverge widely from that logic?

---

### Context

Git's design seems to assume that the physical process of developing changes has some relevant relation to the logical changes that are to be made. However, my experience is that (outside of the most trivial of case) this is rarely the case.

*One specific example of a case where this causes me problems:*

The way that I have done development for the last 10+ years results in the physical progression of the state of my clients almost never being something reasonable to commit/send for review. For example, the working state of a client is almost universally several steps down the line before I even know what the first change/commit will even be, let alone look like. And the edits that end up in that first commit tend to be interspersed in time with other edit that aren't included. As such, I end up retroactively creating a commit/PR underneath the working state and then sending that off for review, while I continue to work on the rest of the project/feature. I then pull out a second commit/PR for the next logical portion of the work and send it for review before the first review is finished.

What am I to do if I get comments from that first review?

- At a minimum, I end up adding more commits to the first PR branch (which is of no relevance to the logic of the change).
- Worse; when I merge/rebase/etc. the second PR to include the follow ups from the first, those changes show up as part of it where they are in fact totally irrelevant.

Similar issues also crop up when other people's changes get merged in.

---

I will grant that tracking the mechanics of how a PR/review went is possibly of value **as part of the PR/review**, but that's absolutely *not* of value as part of the source history. If anything it's just a distraction.

I will also grant that long lived branches (e.g. the 'v2.3.*' branch) should also include merging history (e.g. when bug-fixes/features get backported). But I will content that "feature branches" (where you are doing some work that is intended to be fully merge backed into a branch from its history) should always be small enough and targeted enough that the logical view is that they branch from and immediately merge back into the root branch, even where the physical reality that that weeks or months of work got merged over during development.

---

p.s. While I've been working as a programmer professionally and using source control for over a decade (closer to two if you include some amateur stuff), that has always been something other than Git. So all the git I've done has been on GitHub and either with repos I'm the sole committer to, or for which I don't have commit access to. It's possible that's giving me a warped view on how Git works.

Comment: GIt is quite agnostic to all of this. Git simply stores snapshots, in a Directed Acyclic Graph of commits. That's it. The snapshots are not changesets, they're just snapshots. They have all of your files plus some glue plus your log message. That's it. That's all there is. You pick a commit, you get that commit. Branch names and tag names let you *find* the commits, whose IDs (hash IDs) are otherwise apparently random. Commits let you find their parents.

Comment: Note, too, that Pull Requests ("PR"s on GitHub, for instance) are not part of Git; they're an add-on. If they don't suit your work pattern, you can use Git without using PRs—though use of GitHub (or one of its competitors) will push hard against that: PRs are *their* mechanism.

Comment: Interesting. That brings up some other questions: Is there a way to rebind a branch to an arbitrarily snapshot? Are there reasons/situations where that would be a "really bad idea"? Is there a way to list commits that are not a parent (transitively) of any branch or tag? Does *GitHub* track the history of what snaphots a branch has referred to over time?

Comment: >  Is there a way to rebind a branch to an arbitrarily snapshot?

Yes, because a branch is just a ref pointer to a commit. Though i wouldn't say it's easy to do.

Comment: >  Is there a way to list commits that are not a parent (transitively) of any branch or tag? Ref log will contain records of all commits whether they on a current branch or not. Though orphan / hanging commits will be garbage collected after about a month by default.

Comment: If someone would care to make the above into an answer, I'll try to remember to accept it. (Particularly if it includes *how* to do that rebinding and what foot-guns doing that brings up.)

Comment: Reflogs are local to each repository. Bare repository setups normally have reflogs disabled. Only GitHub could say whether they have theirs enabled or disabled, but since you can't read their reflogs, it's kind of moot anyway.